# Layout в Layout

Tags: yii2

Есть на сайте 3 страницы, у которых помимо основного layout одинаковые элементы в body. 
Как дублирующий код вынести в layout?

Пример Layout

```
<div>
   <div>Дублирующийся код</div>
   <div><?=$content?></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точно так же, как Вы и просто выводите файлы представления. Только к качестве контента будете передавать уже сгенерированное представление без шаблона.

```
$partialContent = $this->renderPartial("some_view", $data);
return $this->render("@frontend/views/layouts/partial_layout", [ "content" => $partialContent ]);
```

В итоге у Вас будет 2 layout:
`main.php`
`partial_layout.php`

И 1 представление:
`some_view.php`